# Opinion on my schema

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema

I've decided to create a database as a personal practice.

The project is based on a fictional English language school called "ESL" located in Japan.

The school has 4 *branches* in 4 different cities.
Whoever wants to join the school has to go through a *trial* lesson. A person from the *staff* conducts the trial lesson and a *teacher* assets the *student* level.
Once the student decided to join the school, they can take *lessons*. Every lesson is private (one teacher and one student)

[image: ESL English language school DB schema]

I'm not sure about the student table. In my project, both potential students and actual students are present in the table. Would it be better to create 2 different tables?

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't know what you mean by `plan` in `student` table. But you could add a `bool` or `varchar` column that can handle the case of actual students or potential students.
2. Since you connected `student` table with `school` table you don't have to connect `school` table with `trial` table again or with `lesson` table again.

I hope this will help you .

Comment: 1- A student can choose different study plans (for example, 4 lessons a month plan, or joining the school during a special campaign). The column "enrolled" in the student table can be Y (yes), N (no), or Q (quit). I planned to use that to figure out if a student is an actual student.
2-A student can take lessons in different school branches, for example, if a student took a trial in school A, they can take lessons in school B or school C.

Comment: In this situation in my view your schema is great, there is no need for 2 different tables, nice work .